# PHP SOAP: Communication to a C++ application

Tags: php, c++, soap, client

I have a C++ SOAP client using [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) and am trying to construct a very simple PHP server (Apache2/PHP5 on Debian) the client can talk to. Unfortunately, I don't understand how I can work with the complex types my web service is using within PHP.

I have a .wsdl that looks like this:

```
<definitions name="NumOps"
    targetNamespace="http://192.168.2.113/numops.wsdl"
    xmlns:tns="http://192.168.2.113/numops.wsdl"
    xmlns:xsd1="http://192.168.2.113/testtypes.xsd"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

<types>
    <schema targetNamespace="http://192.168.2.113/testtypes.xsd"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <element name="AddValRequest">
            <complexType>
                <all>
                    <element name="fVal1" type="float"/>
                    <element name="fVal2" type="float"/>
                </all>
            </complexType>
        </element>
        <element name="AddValResponse">
            <complexType>
                <all>
                    <element name="fResult" type="float"/>
                </all>
            </complexType>
        </element>
    </schema>
</types>

<message name="AddValInput">
    <part name="body" element="xsd1:AddValRequest"/>
</message>
<message name="AddValOutput">
    <part name="body" element="xsd1:AddValResponse"/>
</message>

<portType name="NumOpsPortType">
    <operation name="AddVal">
        <input message="tns:AddValInput"/>
        <output message="tns:AddValOutput"/>
    </operation>
</portType>

<binding name="NumOpsSoapProxy" type="tns:NumOpsPortType">
    <soap:binding style="document"
        transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="AddVal">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://192.168.2.113/"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>

<service name="NumOpsService">
    <port name="NumOpsPort" binding="tns:NumOpsSoapProxy">
        <soap:address location="http://192.168.2.113/"/>
    </port>
</service>

</definitions>
```

My current approach looks like this:

```
<?php

function AddVal($AddValRequest) {
    // How to create a AddValResponse?!
}

$server = new SoapServer(NULL, array("uri"=>"http://192.168.2.113/"));
$server->addFunction("AddVal");
$server->handle();

?>
```

The problem here is that I couldn't anything to get me started on this, and I probably won't solve this guessing. Does anyone know where I could find material to dig into this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
class AddValRequest {
    public $fVal1;
    public $fVal2;
}

class AddValResponse {
    public $fResult;
}

function AddVal(AddValRequest $request) {
    $response = new AddValResponse();
    $response->fResult = $request->fVal1 + $request->fVal2;
    return $response;
}

$server = new SoapServer("numops.wsdl");
$server->addFunction("AddVal");
$server->handle();

?>
```

and should be sufficient to get someone having the same problem started.